# In excel how to search if a number exists in another column

Tags: excel

Currently in excel I have columns A and B. Column A has 18085 entries of which each one is a number that has 16 digits.Column B has 2767 entries of which each one is a number consisting of 8 digits. It is known that the 8 digits of column B have to be the last 8 digits of column A-s numbers.

I need those column A numbers if their last 8 digits match with column B numbers.
How can I match the 2 columns to find the column A values I need?

Regular if expression does not work here in my opinion since the columns numbers are not set in correct order which means for a number on position 1 in column A:1234567891011314 the number on the same position 1 on column B is not 91011314 but could be something else.

Comment: do you store these numbers as a string? Because if you don't Excel will round the 16 digit number down, as it only supports 15 significant digits (at least as far as I know)

Comment: its not a string, its stored as number, however I did not see them automatically rounded to 15 digits

Comment: @rauno45 That is not possible in any version of Excel.  No matter the format of the cell at this time, if you have a 16 digit number, and the last number is not zero, it must have been entered as a text string and retained that data type property.  If you execute `=ISTEXT(cell_ref)`, what do you see?

Comment: @rauno45 You could use the `Advanced Filter` using a formula as the criteria, but might have to make some adjustments in the formula if, for example, the values in Column A are text, and those in column B are numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is stored as text (which is probably the case, cf. my comment), you could do something like:

```
= INDEX( A:A, MATCH( B1, RIGHT( A:A, LEN( B1 ) ), 0 ) )
```

in cell C1 and confirm with Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of just Enter, so it is interpreted as an array formula. Then you can just drag this formula down.

**EDIT:**

If the numbers are somehow not stored as strings (but once again I doubt if that's possible with 16 significant digits), you could slightly change this formula to:

```
= INDEX( A:A, MATCH( B1, VALUE( RIGHT( A:A, LEN( B1 ) ) ), 0 ) )
```

Comment: This seems to work somehow at first. If I could only get my excel to not crash during this procedure would be nice.

Comment: yeah, array formulas are quite resource-heavy. You could try to improve performance a bit by changing "A:A" in the formula to for example "A$1:A$100" depending on your range, although I doubt it would makke a big difference

Answer (score 0):

Use the following array formula.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,RIGHT($A$1:$A$18085,8),0)),"Match Found", "Match Not Found")
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

***Note:*** You must press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` after entering formula.

Comment: this just returns to me either if match is found or not found however that is of no use to me. I need to get all the 16-digit numbers that match these other 2767 numbers by last 8 digits.